# $\vert PSL(4,2) \vert = \vert PSL(3,4) \vert $ but $PSL(4,2) \ncong PSL(3,4)$.

Tags: finite-groups, sylow-theory

Prove that $\vert PSL(4,2) \vert = \vert PSL(3,4) \vert $ but $PSL(4,2) \ncong PSL(3,4)$.

Attempt: I have shown that the orders of the two groups are equal. Then, consider the set of unitriangular matrices in each. They each form a subgroup, furthermore, they are actually the Sylow 2-subgroups in each. This too, is easy to show. The finisher would be to show that the centers of these two Sylow 2-subgroups are not the same, hence they cannot be isomorphic.

How do I show this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is the right one.

In general, one can prove that the center of the [unitriangular matrix group](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Unitriangular_matrix_group) $UT(n,F)$ over a field $F$ is the group of unitriangular matrices $(a_{i \ j})$ such that $a_{i \ j}=0$ for $j>i$ except for $a_{1 \  n}$ which can be any elements of the field. Hence the cardinal of the center is equal to the one of the field.

The proof can be made using [elementary matrices](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix). Suppose that $A=(a_{i \ j})$ is a matrix of the center. Then considering the products $L_{i,j}A$ and $A L_{i,j}$ that have to be equal, you can prove that $a_{k \ l}=0$ for $l > k$ and $(k,l) \neq (1,n)$. Conversely, you can prove that a matrix satisfying those conditions commutes with all the unitriangular matrices.

Now the conclusion comes easily as one center has order $2$ while the other one has order $4$.